# JavaScript typeof

Tags: javascript, typeof

I have a question about a codeschool.com function exercise which concluded as this...

```
function countE() {
  var phrase = prompt("Which phrase would you like to examine?");

  if (typeof(phrase) != "string") {
    alert("This is not a valid entry!");
    return false;
  } else {
    var eCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
      if (phrase.charAt(i) === 'e' || phrase.charAt(i) === 'E') {
        eCount++;
      }
    }
    alert(eCount);
    return true;
  }
}
countE()
```

So.. I wanted to test what is not a string, I wanted to get the alert "This is not a valid entry!".

But, if a prompt only returns a string then why is this 
<< if (typeof(phrase) != "string") >> included in the function?

Sorry to ask this basic question here, codeschool discussion page did not give me an answer and I am very curious to know.

Thank you. J

Comment: try pressing Abort on that prompt. thought it would be simpler to just Check if it is null. PS: typeof does not need ( )

Comment: @Tushar no it will not

Comment: the question tells us how important it is to write comments.

Comment: @JerryChin and/or not trying to jump on questions just to be fast to answer it.

Comment: I still don't get it. Someone please tell me why this function may have been written like that regarding the typeof. Is it just wrong? If so how should it be written? If not, how can I get that 'This is not a valid entry' to alert? For me pressing esc or cancel just alerts "The are 0 E's in this phrase!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing `Cancel` or <kbd>Esc</kbd> will return `null`. This is the check you should be interested in.

[image: cancel]

[image: preview]

Reference: [MDN `prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

**Note:** You don't need to use `()` with `typeof`. So change it to:

```
if (typeof phrase != "string") {
```

---

**Other Scenarios**

When you are expecting a number, like age or something, you can use:

```
if (isNaN(phrase)) {
```

The above might help you to decide if it is a number or not.

Comment: I still don't get it. Someone please tell me why this function may have been written like that regarding the typeof. Is it just wrong? If so how should it be written? If not, how can I get that 'This is not a valid entry' to alert? For me pressing esc or cancel just alerts "The are 0 E's in this phrase!"

Comment: @James Can you show your code then? It definitely returns null, and null is an object and not string.

Comment: function countE() {
  var phrase = prompt("Which phrase would you like to examine?");

  if (typeof(phrase) != "string") {
    alert("This is not a valid entry!");
    return false;
  } else {
    var eCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
      if (phrase.charAt(i) === 'e' || phrase.charAt(i) === 'E') {
        eCount++;
      }
    }
    alert("There are " + eCount + " E's in this phrase!");
    return true;
  }
}
countE()

Comment: This is the code Praveen. I am really new to coding so maybe I am missing something very obvious or just don't understand properly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I figured out my issue....
I use Safari - in Safari, pressing esc or cancel will alert '0'.
In Chrome pressing esc or cancel will alert 'That is not a valid entry!'
Can anyone tell me how to get Safari to alert correctly as Chrome is doing?